# Is it possible to train directly on actual data?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

For example, if I want to develop a chitchat bot, and I already have a corpus with dialog like the following:

```
-- Are you a student?
  -- No, I am a scientist.
...
```

Can I train a model directly on this data without going through the regular NLU and Core processes, such as create the NLU data and stories data? In chitchat, it's hard to define the intent, if my corpus is a little large. There can be potentially too many intents. So it seems not to be good to use intent-slot-dm flow to develop the model?

Does RASA provide a way to directly train on the data?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible with the Rasa Stack.
If you model goal oriented use cases, this should be not a big problem. However, for chitchat this can indeed be a bit tricky. Try to see whether you can break down the most frequent chitchat messages in intents, and then handle them in stories.